# Best practice to format MMyyyy to MMyy

Tags: java, simpledateformat

Good day,

The following is my sample code:

```
String month = "09";

String year = "2014";

String monthYear = "092014";
```

The `monthYear` format is `MMyyyy`, I wish to format it to become `MMyy`. Thus, I am doing it as follow:

Method 1:

```
final SimpleDateFormat oriMonthYear = new SimpleDateFormat( "MMyyyy" );
final SimpleDateFormat changeMonthYear = new SimpleDateFormat( "MMyy" );

String newMonthYear = changeMonthYear.format( oriMonthYear.parse( month + year) );
```

This give me correct output, but I am not sure am I doing it by stupid way or not. I believe it should be another best practice and smart to way to do it. Kindly advise.

Comment: If this works and you're searching for how to improve it then please move your question to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Do you have dates before 2000 or after 2099? How do you plan to handle them?

Comment: This looks fine to me.  Just becareful, SimpleDateFormat is NOT thread safe.  "It is recommended to create separate format instances for each thread."

Answer (score 0):

`SimpleDateFormat` class is to format dates and your inputs are `String` therefore you problem is about formatting strings not dates.

I'd suggest something like:

```
private String formatDate(String month, String year) {
  return month + year.substring(2);
}
```

Note1: you should validate the inputs in the method above, it is only meant to give you a quick idea of what I would do.

Note2: You can also look into String.format(), more info [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...))

Comment: I'd really only recommend this as long as just cutting two digits off is what you want. Once you want to adjust the value in any other way, working with dates is cleaner and more natural.

Answer (score 0):

If monthYear is alwas in the format MMYYYY you can use:

```
String newMonthYear = monthYear.replaceAll("(?<=\\d{2})\\d{2}(?=\\d{2})", "");
```

Comment: This is one of those problems where using a regular expression serves no purpose and makes it just unnecessarily hard to understand what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `YearMonth` in Java 8 or later like below

```
YearMonth
        .parse(yearMonth, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(MMYYYY))
        .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(MMYY));
```